# remove mime attachments with php

Tags: php, imap, mime

Google has provided me with loads of resources on how to add attachments and how to extract attachments from a imap message using PHP, but I am unable to find anything to demonstrate how to remove mime attachments from an imap email.

Any suggestions ??

I have tried using the imap_mail_copy and imap_mail_move functions, hoping that it would offer an option to copy / move without attachments but unfortunately it does not.

I've spent several hours searching and experimenting but so far have not come up with any solutions

Comment: Do you have Pear set up? There are a bunch of libraries that might be useful to you, I've used several in the past for creating inline content.

Comment: did you ever have any luck with this?  I too am trying to setup email servers where the mail attachments are stripped and stored on a share.

Answer (score 0):

Try cut parts with regex or explode:

```
$mimeParts = explode('\r\n\r\n', $mimeMessageContent);
```

and remove parts with text: `Content-Disposition`: